# Installing windows w/ boot camp is not working, getting 'Disk error' on startup to Windows drive

Tags: windows, macos, windows-xp, macbook, boot-camp

I'm trying to install Windows XP on my macbook w/ boot camp, like I've done before, but I'm getting a 'Disk error' now whenever I try. I've reformatted the machine with OSX 10.5 on a Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

Here's how far I get:
- Use boot camp to partition the drive, it then says to insert the cd, and I can press a button after the partitioning is done to restart and install.
- after the restart occurs, the windows setup begins, and I install, there is a C drive (fat) and an option to install on this drive and leave it as is (or I can format as NTFS at this step), so I install on C as it is
- after the install is done the computer restarts, immediately after the restart though I get a 'Disk error' message is DOS at the top left of my screen, directly after 'Press any key to boot from CD.."

After first getting this error I tried installing windows again using a quick NTFS format, but got the same error w/ an addtional message about some missing dll afterwards, so I tried booting into OSX after this and restored the drive w/ boot camp, then tried again, but got the same error once again..

An idea what I can do to resolve this issue?

**Update**

> Here's the error that I get when I
>   format the drive as NTFS, instead of
>   the 'Disk error':
>
> Windows could not start because the
>   following file is missing or corrupt:
>   \system32\hal.dll Please
>   re-install a copy of the above file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1722) I realized my mistake, I either deleted the bootcamp partition and created a new one, or used the "Leave the current file system intact (no changes)" option, both of which I should not do. I had to install to the BOOTCAMP partition, do not delete it, then I was asked about formatting the partition, which I choose NTFS for, and then that worked!